# Segmentation fault, stopping uvc camera driver

Tags: ros, logitech, uvc-cam, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have an extra logitech QuickCam Messenger VGA Webcam. When I simply try to run it with uvc_cam, it give me a error "Segmentation fault, stopping uvc camera driver.
[ERROR] [1351517497.937394454]: Segmentation fault, stopping uvc camera driver.
[uvc_cam_node-1] process has died [pid 7268, exit code -11].
log files: /home/btian/.ros/log/916ac8ea-21c8-11e2-9c54-002710a9471c/uvc_cam_node-1*.log"

The integrated cam of my laptop works fine with the uvc_cam. I installed guvcview, and it can switch between the two cameras without any problem. I tried the logitech webcam on another PC, same error. What should I do with the uvc_cam? Thanks!

Tian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46995/segmentation-fault,-stopping-uvc-camera-driver/) by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on ROS Answers with karma: 710 on 2012-10-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-11-21**:
same problem here

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2014-07-25**:
I have the same problem but in ARM hydro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I have encountered this problem again. Thanks to http://answers.ros.org/question/9089/what-driver-should-i-use-for-my-usb-camera/, an old post, I have tried some other drivers. Finally I found that gscam [gscam](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam) is very universal. It supports my 8 years old logitech quickcam and Philips SPC900, which is a very popular camera for robotic fans. Both of the cameras are with c-mount, easily change to wide angle lens.

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1